# Can somebody help me out in this error if 0<upperpipes[0]['x']<5: KeyError: 0

Tags: python, pygame, keyerror

This is the Code:-
I'm facing the issue with `upperpipes`. Either It is not able to access the key of the 1st element of the `upperpipes` i.e `'x'` or what else I can't understand. Help me out in solving this error

```py
def mainGame():
    upperpipes=[
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH + 200, 'y': newPipe1[0]['y']},
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH + 200 + (SCREENWIDTH / 2), 'y': newPipe2[0]['y']}
                ]

    lowerpipes = [
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH + 200, 'y': newPipe1[1]['y']},
        {'x': SCREENWIDTH + 200 + (SCREENWIDTH / 2), 'y': newPipe2[1]['y']}
                 ]      
     
        #Add A NEW PIPE WHEN THE fIRST IS ABOUT TO cross THE LEFT MOST PART OF SCREEN
        if 0<upperpipes[0]['x']<5:
            newpipe=getRandomPipe()
            upperpipes.append(newpipe[0])
            lowerpipes.append(newpipe[1])
```

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your application there is some code code between the initialization and the `if`-statement. Very likely there is some code that removes pipes and the list is empty.

Comment: where is the code for getRandomPipe()? Also python doesn't use CamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

The list seems empty. Check if the list is empty:

<s>`if 0<upperpipes[0]['x']<5:`</s>

```py
if not upperpipes or 0 < upperpipes[0]['x'] < 5:
    # [...]
```